# Was the Paw Patrol logo inspired by the 1973 Doctor Who logo?

Tags: doctor-who, paw-patrol

Recently, Doctor Who announced a new logo that appears to be for its 2023 season, coinciding with the announcement of it coming to Disney Plus:

[image]

A number of comparisons have been drawn between this logo and the Paw Patrol logo, seen on both [Twitter](https://wegotthiscovered.com/tv/whovians-feel-ruff-after-doctor-who-regenerates-into-paw-patrol/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualUK/comments/yd6m1f/new_doctor_who_logo_reminds_me_of_paw_patrol/) ([alt](https://www.reddit.com/r/doctorwho/comments/yd83y8/the_new_doctor_who_logo/)).

In reality, the new logo is a variant of the 1973 Doctor Who Logo, which came many years before Paw Patrol.

[image]

Therefore, we can ask - is there any evidence that the Paw Patrol logo itself was inspired by the 1973 Doctor Who logo?

Comment: It looks more like the earlier Kaos logo from Get Smart to me.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a stretch - the Paw Patrol logo is clearly based around the idea of a police shield badge, and lots of logos have the curved text over a background shape like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't *appear* so. We have some early 'concept art' of the logo which shows the evolution of the artwork, from its earliest styling as a [bone on a shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5UL0.png), then into a [2D shield with extruded writing](https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/PAW_Patrol#2012%E2%80%932013), then into its final form with a slightly more prominent badge and writing that follows the curve of the top of the badge.

[image]

Although it's certainly possible that the makers saw the Doctor Who logo and were (consciously or subconsciously) trying to ape it, it seems more likely that they just went with a fairly generic "[police badge with things written on it](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/60/a7/12/60a71293dad7865c2f91b3a1e51a53f2.jpg)" design and made the writing 'pop' more by making it curved and extrusive.

Comment: I was thinking along slightly different lines; TV show logos with the name [printed over a police-type badge](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_PfeoPMUjPrM/S58ThtQG9VI/AAAAAAAAA5I/GMPEKfDFG3U/s400/Dragnet_logo.png), [or this one](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LPtklmW3qEY/VLXYQIK4cOI/AAAAAAAALE0/5nl_rWeMKzw/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-01-13%2Bat%2B1.43.11%2BPM.png).

Comment: @DavidW - Both clearly inspired by police badges have writing on them

Comment: True enough; I'm not really quibbling with your answer.  Just trying to push the priority date, of using that pattern for a TV show logo, far enough in the past that a claimed borrowing from Dr. Who is obviously silly.

Comment: @DavidW - Agreed. The logo design trope predates Doctor Who, let alone Dragnet

Comment: Good enough for me. I didn't immediately make the connection either. But enough people online seemed to think they were similar enough that I thought perhaps there might be some evidence otherwise.